# Changing Cell Validation List source in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of cells in a CALC sheet that are validated using named ranges from another DATA_VIC sheet. The calculation sheet is generic - but the data it's pulling from is geographically (Australia State) specific (VIC - Victoria). All the named ranges in this data sheet end in the state "VIC".

Now I have to modify the CALC sheet to be able to use data from two different states, depending on which state (VIC or ALD) is selected into a specific cell (selSTATE) in the CALC sheet.

I am looking at dynamic named ranges to solve the issue (separate question elsewhere). But I also tried to use VBA to change the Validation List on the cells that would be affected by the change. The code looks something like this:

```
Sub ChangeValidation(strState As String)
Dim rng As Range ' rng object for looping

' Loop through the range of all user entry cells in the sheet
For Each rng In Range("AllUserEntryCells")

    ' Check to see if this cell is a validation list
    If rng.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then

        ' Check to see if the validation list is State-Specific (Ends in either QLD or VIC)
        If InStr("QLDVIC", Right(rng.Validation.Formula1, 3)) <> 0 Then

            ' Check to see if the state is not set to the current state
            If Right(rng.Validation.Formula1, 3) <> strState Then

                ' Set the validation list to the new state list
                rng.Validation.Formula1 = Left(rng.Validation.Formula1, Len(rng.Validation.Formula1) - 3) & strState

            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The problem is the assignment of **.Validation.Formula1 =** of course - the property is read only. Any suggestions on how to get round this?

[image]

Comment: Damn! So simple. My question was on the back of several google searches but I did not come across the Modify method. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
With Range("A1").Validation

    Debug.Print .Formula1         '>> =LST_VIC

    .Modify Formula1:=Replace(.Formula1, "VIC", "QLD")

    Debug.Print .Formula1         '>> =LST_QLD

End With
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.modify